# Game Update in Libgdx

Tags: java, libgdx, game-loop

In libgdx, the game loop is the render() method. But why is that, and is there a way where I can make an update() method that is called 60 times a second? As in the update() method, I would add the game logic, and leave the rendering to the render method.
Basically, separate methods, and the update() method called 60 times per second using Libgdx with java.

Comment: I think you should wait a bit longer to accept an answer. This question has only been viewed 9 times (at the time of be writing this). It is usually best to wait a bit to see if more answers come in.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no specific game loop in libGDX because it is event-driven. And still, you can see the render method as the main loop.

You've got it right - usually, this is where you update the game logic before you do the rendering.

What you can do is to create a class responsible for the logic and a class responsible for the rendering. Then in your render method you write

```
@Override
public void render(float deltaTime) {
    if(!paused)
        LogicClass.update(deltaTime);
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 0);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    RenderClass.render(deltaTime);
}
```

You can read more about the life cycle in libGDX in its wiki on github:
https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/The-life-cycle.

Comment: Hmmm... This might work :D All I need to do is find out how to make it update at 60 times per second.

Comment: You can limit the FPS by changing the configuration. This is a similar question to yours and you will find the answer useful: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19699801/dewitters-game-loop-in-libgdxandorid)